# Error expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token

Tags: c++

I'm getting 3 errors when compiling my code against my college professors main.cpp

7   0   **In file included from main.cpp**

3   8   **[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.'** token

28  C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\school\Makefile.win    **recipe for target 'main.o' failed**

Here is my ntree.h file

```
* Ntree.h - header and implementation file for classes Tnode, Ntree //this line is the one getting the error
* Limitations: values cannot contain '(' and ')' characters.
* Can be changed by redefining TOKEN_BEGIN and TOKEN_END
#ifndef _NTREE_H
#define _NTREE_H
#define TOKEN_BEGIN '('
#define TOKEN_END ')'
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
template <typename T> 
class Tnode
{
    private:
        T value;
        std::vector<Tnode*> children;
    public:
        Tnode (T data = {});        // copy constructor
        ~Tnode();                   // destructor
        T getValue() const;         // gets the value
        size_t getChildrenCount() const;    
        Tnode* getChild(size_t n) const;    // get child by number
        void setValue(T data);      // sets for value
        void addChild(Tnode *node); // add child node
        void addChild(T data);      // creates a node and adds child with a value
        bool operator== ( Tnode<T> & other) const; // overload operator
};
template <typename T> 
class Ntree{
    private:
        Tnode<T>* rootPtr;
        int numOfNodes;
        // utility function get node with current value
        Tnode<T>* getNodeByValue(Tnode<T> *node, T data);
        // utility function get value from the stream
        std::string getToken(std::ifstream & ifs);
        void serialize(std::ofstream & ofs, Tnode<T> *node);
    public:
        Ntree();        // default constructor
        Ntree(T val);   // constructor with root initialization
        ~Ntree();       // destructor
        void addChildren(T parent, std::initializer_list<T> ini_list);
        void serialize(std::string fname);
        void deserialize(std::string fname);    
        bool operator== (Ntree<T> & other);
};
```

Comment: Fix your "comments" at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Try Commenting the first 3 lines. Are you sure you know what the first few lines mean?

Comment: if i comment those three lines i get tons of errors